# Grabbing the account detail of the email from which the service is invoked

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-script

I have a published service on my script. And I pass it to an email from which the script could be called when someone clicks on the service URL. I want to grab the username of the account from which the the service is invoked. For example say the username of the email from which the service is called is example@account.com, I want to pass the username 'example' back to the script for further processing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless this is a Google consumer account, you can't do it.  If it's Google Apps, use

`Session.getActiveUser()`